# Ruby: Reducing Repetition

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner and wrote a script for the following question below in ruby. I read that repetition isn't recommended and would like to reduce the repetition of if, elsif, else statements but can't seem to find a way.

Old-school Roman numerals. In the early days of Roman numer- als, the Romans didn’t bother with any of this new-fangled sub- traction “IX” nonsense. No sir, it was straight addition, biggest to littlest—so 9 was written “VIIII,” and so on. Write a method that when passed an integer between 1 and 3000 (or so) returns a string containing the proper old-school Roman numeral. In other words, old_roman_numeral 4 should return 'IIII'. Make sure to test your method on a bunch of different numbers. Hint: Use the inte- ger division and modulus methods on page 37.
For reference, these are the values of the letters used:
I =1 V=5 X=10 L=50 C=100 D=500 M=1000

Here is my script...

```
puts "What is your number?"
n = gets.chomp
num = n.to_i
number = ""
l = n.length
i = 0

while true
    if num > 3000
        puts "Enter another number."
    elsif l == 0
        break
    else
        if l == 4
            number += "M" * n[i].to_i
            l -= 1
        i += 1
    elsif l == 3
        if 1 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 4
            number += "C" * n[i].to_i
        elsif n[i].to_i == 5
            number += "D"
        elsif 6 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 9
            number += "D" + "C" * (n[i].to_i - 5)
        end
            l -= 1
            i += 1
        elsif l == 2
            if 1 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 4
                number += "X" * n[i].to_i
            elsif n[i].to_i == 5
                number += "L"
            elsif 6 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 9
                number += "L" + "X" * (n[i].to_i - 5)
            end
            l -= 1
            i += 1
        else
            if 1 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 4
                number += "I" * n[i].to_i 
            elsif n[i].to_i == 5
                number += "V"
            elsif 6 <= n[i].to_i && n[i].to_i <= 9
                number += "V" + "I" * (n[i].to_i - 5)
            end
            l -= 1
            i += 1
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think the easiest way is to rewrite this,  if you paid attention to the hints in the problem statement, ie, use modulus, this becomes almost trivial

Comment: What is "numer- als"? What is "sub- traction"? What is "inte- ger"? You can't even cite correctly? What is "littlest"? Is there such word? What is page 37?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use integer division or modulus, but it might be instructive.

```
puts "What is your number?"
input = gets.to_i

numerals = {
  1000 => "M",
  500 => "D",
  100 => "C",
  50 => "L",
  10 => "X",
  5 => "V",
  1 => "I"
}

digits = []
numerals.each do |n, digit|
  while input >= n
    digits << digit
    input = input - n
  end
end

puts digits.join
```

Comment: Why do you push into an array and join them later? Is it more efficient than directly concatenating to a string?

Comment: Your `chomp` is redundant.

Comment: I bet string concatenation is more performant, but not measurable for anything reasonable. Agree about the chomp.

Comment: numerals.each do |n, digit|  
    digits << digit * (input / n)
    input = input % n  
end

Answer (score 1):

Another way, that builds a string, as @sawa suggested, rather than constructing an array and then using `join`:

```
numerals = {
  1000 => "M",
  500 => "D",
  100 => "C",
  50 => "L",
  10 => "X",
  5 => "V",
  1 => "I"
}

input = 9658

numerals.each_with_object('') do |(n, digit),str|
  nbr, input = input.divmod(n)
  str << digit*nbr
end
  #=> "MMMMMMMMMDCLVIII"
```